# Tkinter create_image() retains PNG transparency but Button(image) does not

Tags: python, tkinter, transparency, tkinter-canvas

TkVersion = 8.6, Python version 3.7.3

Im trying to create a button in python with tkinter using a PNG image. The transparent corners of the image are transparent depending on which widget I use. It seems `canvas.create_image` is the only widget retaining the transparency.

First I added the image on a canvas using `create_image(0,0, image=button)` and it works fine - the rounded corners are transparent.

But then when I try to implement it as an actual button using `Button()` and `create_window()` widgets, the corners are filled with white.

```
button = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="button.png")

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=200, heigh=200, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid()
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,199,199, fill="blue")

canvas.create_image(0,0, image=button, anchor="nw")
```

[image: works][]

```
button = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="button.png")

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=200, heigh=200, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid()
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,199,199, fill="blue")

buttonWidget = tk.Button(root, image=button)
canvas.create_window(0,0, window=buttonWidget, anchor="nw")
```

[image: doesnt work]

How can I make the PNG button corners transparent?

Here is also the button image:
[image: button]

Comment: Use the image instead of `Button` as your *Button*. Bind `"<Button-1>"` event to the image.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I renamed the button widget to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own custom button class inherited from canvas and use it just like you use `Button()`. I made one for you hopefully you find it helpful.

[image]

**Custom Button Class:**

Save this class in a separate file as `imgbutton.py` and then import it to your main file. Also make sure it is in the same directory as the main file is in. Or you can just keep it on the top of the main file after your imports.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Imgbutton(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master=None, image=None, command=None, **kw):

        # Declared style to keep a reference to the original relief
        style = kw.get("relief", "groove")        

        if not kw.get('width') and image:
            kw['width'] = image.width()
        else: kw['width'] = 50

        if not kw.get('height') and image:
            kw['height'] = image.height()
        else: kw['height'] = 24

        kw['relief'] = style
        kw['borderwidth'] = kw.get('borderwidth', 2)
        kw['highlightthickness'] = kw.get('highlightthickness',0)

        super(Imgbutton, self).__init__(master=master, **kw)

        self.set_img = self.create_image(kw['borderwidth'], kw['borderwidth'], 
                anchor='nw', image=image)

        self.bind_class( self, '<Button-1>', 
                    lambda _: self.config(relief='sunken'), add="+")

        # Used the relief reference (style) to change back to original relief.
        self.bind_class( self, '<ButtonRelease-1>', 
                    lambda _: self.config(relief=style), add='+')

        self.bind_class( self, '<Button-1>', 
                    lambda _: command() if command else None, add="+")
```

---

**Here is an Example how to use it**

```
import tkinter as tk
from imgbutton import Imgbutton    # Import the custom button class

root = tk.Tk()
root['bg'] = 'blue'

but_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='button.png')

but = Imgbutton(root, image=but_img, bg='blue', 
            command=lambda: print("Button Image"))
but.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you setting the button style in `style = kw.get('relief', 'groove')` ? Isn't 'relief' a key for kw dictionary and 'groove' the corresponding value? Why is `kw.get('relief')` not enough?

Comment: Just to keep the reference of `relief` so the program know what was the previous `relief` to switch back to when the button release event happens

Comment: sorry now I understand 'groove' is the default value for 'relief' in `style = kw.get('relief', 'groove')`. I am very much a beginner in coding and I want to fully understand the syntax you are using :)

Comment: It's okay, if you wanna learn more about Tkinter check this [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).

Comment: If I may still ask why you are setting width 50 and height 24 if the parameters are not given and it is an image? Are they just arbitrary numbers?

Comment: That is because by default a canvas is quite big as compared to a button so I set size similar to a button in case you decide to use this button without an image. It doesn't do any harm if you remove it.